# Pandas filter list by using unique python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to below

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'cat1':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'], 'cat2':[['X','Y'], ['F'], ['X','Y'], ['Y'], ['Y'], ['Y'], ['Z'], ['P','W'],['L','K'],['L','K'],['L','K']]})
```

The output is

```
   cat1    cat2
0     A  [X, Y]
1     A     [F]
2     A  [X, Y]
3     B     [Y]
4     B     [Y]
5     C     [Y]
6     C     [Z]
7     C  [P, W]
8     D  [L, K]
9     D  [L, K]
10    D  [L, K]
```

I would like to filter out B and D, B and D only has 'Y' and ['L','K'].

Desired output:

```
   cat1    cat2
0     A  [X, Y]
1     A     [F]
2     A  [X, Y]
3     C     [Y]
4     C     [Z]
5     C  [P, W]
```

I have tried `df.groupby(['cat1'])['cat2'].unique()`yet, as it is a list column. It will not work.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just to be clear, you only want A and C rows of Cat1 right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python `list`s are not hashtable, so necessary convert them to `tuple`s or `string`s, then use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and filter by not equal with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['cat2'].apply(tuple).groupby(df['cat1']).transform('nunique').ne(1)]
#alternative
#df = df[df['cat2'].astype('str').groupby(df['cat1']).transform('nunique').ne(1)]
print (df)
  cat1    cat2
0    A  [X, Y]
1    A     [F]
2    A  [X, Y]
5    C     [Y]
6    C     [Z]
7    C  [P, W]
```